# Delimitar tabela dentro de um modal com css

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho um modal que mostra uma tabela com algumas informações adicionais a partir de uma outra tabela (Chamarei de **tabelaP**), o problema e que a tabelaP possui muitos itens, o que a torna relativamente grande, e a tabela que está no modal é gerada a partir dela, tornando o Modal gigantesco também, o problema é que a tabelaP quando imprimida, me dá a opção de rolagem, porém o modal não tem essa opção de rolagem deixando a tabela enorme e cortando a mesma:
Então gostaria de fixar um tamanho para o meu Modal e que caso a tabela seja grande, tenha uma opção de rolagem dentro do modal:

*Segue CSS: modal_qm.css*

```
    body {
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', arial;
}
.wrap {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.btn {
  background: #808080;
  border: #808280 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .1s ease;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #808280;
}
.btn.btn-big {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.btn-close {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
.btn-close:hover {
  color: #919191;
}
.modal:before {
  content: "";
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.modal:target:before {
  display: block;
}
.modal:target .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  top: 20%;
}
.modal-dialog {
  background: #fefefe;
  border: #333 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 800px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);
  transform: translate(0, -500%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.modal-header {
  border-bottom: #eee solid 1px;
}
.modal-header h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.modal-footer {
  border-top: #eee solid 1px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Segue o trecho HTML/PHP que gera o Modal com a tabela:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modal_qm.css"/>

    <div class="wrap">
  <a href="#modal-one" class="btn btn-big">Tabelas consultadas</a>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Tabelas - QuotesMem</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">x</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <table>
        <tbody>
        <?php

         echo '<tr align="center">';
         echo '<th>' .Papel. '</th>';
    for($h = 1; $h < $k + 1; $h++){
      $nome = "Tabela Server";
      $hora_top = "$nome $h";
      echo '<th>' .$hora_top. '</th>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';

for($n = 0; $n < $j; $n++){
      echo '<tr>';
      $trans = $mat[$n][(($k*2)+3)];
      echo '<td class='.$trans.'>' .$mat[$n][0]. '</td>';
      for($o = 0; $o < $k ; $o++){
        echo '<td class='.$trans.'>'.$mat[$n][(($k*2)+2)].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
        ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Voltar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Modal fica "maior" que a tela e não traz a barra de rolagem]

Modal fica "maior" que a tela e não traz a barra de rolagem

**Edit1:** Alterei a pergunta para mostrar a tabela como ela está agora

Comment: Tentou definir um `height` para o modal e dar `overflow: auto;`?

Comment: @I_like_trains, esse modal eu peguei "Meio pronto", então não sei aonde devo definir essas funções que vc me falou

Comment: Qual foi o plugin de modal que vc usou? Tem o link? Por acaso vc está usando Bootstrap, pois ele tem o próprio modal que tb pode ser adaptado. Sem saber o que usou fica meio difícil te responder.

Comment: @hugocsl, usei apenas Css, nada de plugin ou bootstrap, todo o CSS q usei está na pergunta

Comment: Então dei uma arrumada no seu HTML que estava com algum problemas de formatação. Depois vc pode ajustar o seu código dentro dele, pq o que importa mesmo e colocar um valor de altura no Modal e habilitar o Overflow. Depois olha a resposta lá e se tiver algum problema me fala.

Comment: Olá @hugocsl, fiz as alterações conforme vc sugeriu e o erro persiste, vou adicionar uma foto na pergunta para que fique mais claro o que está ocorrendo

Comment: Alterei os codigos da pergunta com o que está na minha maquina agr

Comment: Vc pode tentar colocar  max-height: 120px; e o overflow:auto na tabela para ver se funciona

Comment: Coloquei e nada aconteceu :(

Comment: Funcionou cara, só tive que limpar o cache :D

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: hahaha boa garoto! Boa sorte com o projeto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara tive que dar uma pequena mexida na parte onde vc chama a tabela por que o HTML não estava bem formatado.

Além disso precisei colocar alguns estilos na `.modal-body`

Que ficou dessa forma:

```
.modal-body {
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Veja como ficou o resultado. Agora vc tem um Scroll dentro do Modal. *(**OBS:** para ter o scroll o conteúdo tem que ser maior que o max-height, e o overflow:auto só abilita quando esse conteúdo for maior que a altura)*

**Mande exibir na "Página toda" para ver o resultado melhor**

```css
    body {
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', arial;
}
.wrap {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.btn {
  background: #808080;
  border: #808280 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .1s ease;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #808280;
}
.btn.btn-big {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.btn-close {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
.btn-close:hover {
  color: #919191;
}
.modal:before {
  content: "";
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.modal:target:before {
  display: block;
}
.modal:target .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  top: 20%;
}
.modal-dialog {
  background: #fefefe;
  border: #333 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 800px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);
  transform: translate(0, -500%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.modal-header {
  border-bottom: #eee solid 1px;
}
.modal-header h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.modal-footer {
  border-top: #eee solid 1px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
          <a href="#modal-one" class="btn btn-big">Tabelas consultadas</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h2>Tabelas - QuotesMem</h2>
              <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">x</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                
              <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <tr>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates veniam explicabo labore nam vel praesentium, ipsa architecto reiciendis doloribus, voluptas numquam amet recusandae. Sequi, voluptas eius magni quidem cumque aut sunt ad aliquid! Nobis odio doloremque dolorem inventore cumque, officia, soluta recusandae ab quisquam, vero dolores quasi tempore error amet distinctio ipsam beatae cupiditate. Voluptatem tempore velit repudiandae quae, ullam doloremque sed nulla vitae tenetur ipsam fugit suscipit possimus sunt ad delectus et earum. Ea debitis similique consectetur error itaque nostrum quia earum quasi, beatae veniam quas porro, enim sed unde aliquid quo, dolorum excepturi? A non perspiciatis harum tempora.
<br><br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates veniam explicabo labore nam vel praesentium, ipsa architecto reiciendis doloribus, voluptas numquam amet recusandae. Sequi, voluptas eius magni quidem cumque aut sunt ad aliquid! Nobis odio doloremque dolorem inventore cumque, officia, soluta recusandae ab quisquam, vero dolores quasi tempore error amet distinctio ipsam beatae cupiditate. Voluptatem tempore velit repudiandae quae, ullam doloremque sed nulla vitae tenetur ipsam fugit suscipit possimus sunt ad delectus et earum. Ea debitis similique consectetur error itaque nostrum quia earum quasi, beatae veniam quas porro, enim sed unde aliquid quo, dolorum excepturi? A non perspiciatis harum tempora.

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
           
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn">Voltar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma nova `class` (ou aproveite a `class` 'modal-body' mesmo), defina o `height` e adicione a propriedade `overflow: auto`, isso deve resolver o seu problema.

Porém, precisa se atentar a estrutura do seu código.

- A tag `<center>` não é suportada no HTML5, veja a versão do seu `html`.
- Não é preciso colocar dentro da modal as tags `<html>` e `<body>`. Essa tags já foram definidas na sua página.
- Caso queira definir melhor a estrutura de sua `<table>`, utilize `<thead>` e `<tbody>`.